# How to send and display image via fcm message? (not in push notification tab)[Multiple Questions]

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

First of all, this post includes multiple questions that I have in my mind but I hope all are related to each other.

I can send notification messages using Notifications composer in the Firebase console and also send text messages using key/value pairs in Custom data. As far as I understand, it is named as "notification messages" unless key/value pairs are included (so this is data messages I guess).

My question is that I don't know how to deliver images with these key/value pairs and want to be sure the way I should go on searching for. Also I need to this working for all cases whether the app is in foreground or background. Do I need to use methods like HTTP Post/Request, Volley, Picasso? Can I use Firebase Storage as an image source to implement these methods?

I watched so many videos and read documents along with basic ones like [About FCM messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) and tried to understand them but confused a lot.

I think I found some useful links and topics like [Firebase Expandable Notification Show image when app is in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38504078/firebase-expandable-notification-show-image-when-app-is-in-background) and [Android Tutorials : Firebase Push Notification Tutorial](http://androidbash.com/firebase-push-notification-android/) but these are only valid for push notification tab as far as I understand. Or should I use this? --> 
[Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)

Also, what is the point of using fcm cloud messaging system if `Maximum payload for both message types is 4KB`? Do we have to use external sources for the exceeding case?

I'm inexperienced on this field and also in Stack Overflow but trying to learn so forgive me if I made a conceptual mistake or broke the rules of "Asking Questions" on this platform.

Comment: I am afraid you have entangled lot of things and need to clear one by one, , break down your question one at a time and try to find out exactly what you need, for example try to find out how the server side integration of FCM works and all and ask a specific question to that. This question will turn out to be vague.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and your attention. I think you are right so I'll search for more information and then update my post to become more clear. Hope I will manage to understand and this time come back with the answers to my own questions.